# error term of taylor series

Tags: calculus

I've been posed the following questions and i'm struggling to solve (b) and (c):
[image]

I'm not exactly sure how to use taylor's theorem in this case, any suggestions?

Comment: Last question: which form does the remainder have in the version of the [Taylor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) you learned?

Comment: $(x-c)^n$ for a taylor series centered around $c$

Answer (score 1):

So, the third order term $R_2(x)$ should be of the form $$\frac{f'''(z)}{3!}(x-16)^3$$ for some $z$ in between $x$ and $16$ by Taylor's theorem.

The third derivative of $x^{1/2}$ can be evaluated to $$f'''(z) = \frac{3}{8}z^{-5/2} \; .$$

So you need to look for which values of $x$, $|R_2(x)|<0.01$. Can you take it from here with the hint in (c)?

EDIT: To complete the answer, since OP already solved the problem,

$$\left|\frac{f'''(z)}{3!}(x-16)^3\right|=\left|\frac{3}{3! 8}z^{-5/2}(x-16)^3\right|\leq\left|\frac{1}{2^{14}}p^3\right|$$

where in the last step I've made use of the fact that for $z>16$,

$$z^{-5/2}<16^{-5/2} = 2^{-10}$$

and where I also put $x=16+p$. Then requesting $|R_2(x)|<0.01$ amounts to

$$p<\sqrt[3]{0.01 \cdot 2^{14}} \approx 5.4719 \; .$$

Comment: for part (c), is the domain $16<x<21.47$?